# Including javascript in a meteor template

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am very new to meteor and am trying to run a page that makes use of flowplayer video player.

Normally all I'd need to do to install flowplayer is add one js and css file to the page.

I've added these files to the /public folder and added links to them in the head.  The files appear on the page but the player does not appear as normal - it seems as though in page javascript doesn't run as it would in a standard page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the library exposes only a global `var` (and not a window global), then you should drop it in the [`[projectRoot]/client/compatibility`](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#special-directories) special folder, so that Meteor knows it should not wrap the JS file in a separate scope, but include it as an old-fashioned library (similar to a `<script>` tag).

Answer (score 2):

One pure js solution is to load the script in the `onRendered` Funktion:

```
Template.yourTemplate.onRendered(function() {
      $(document).ready(function() {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type="text/javascript";
        script.src = "REMOTE_SCRIPT_URL";
        $("#script_div").append(script);
      });
});
```

Or you can use for example [meteor-external-file-loader](https://github.com/davidd8/meteor-external-file-loader) for including the external files.

Comment: Would be beneficial to include a mechanism not to dynamically import the same `src` more than once. Otherwise, since the template may be rendered several times, this code will import the external script as many times. Some libraries and client code might break due to objects reference mismatch once the library is re-imported and re-executed.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for helpers:

```
Template.body.helpers({
  tasks: [    
    { text: 'This is task 1' },    
    { text: 'This is task 2' },    
    { text: 'This is task 3' },    
  ],    
});
```

and in your Template HTML:

```
  <div class="container">
    <header>    
      <h1>Todo List</h1>    
    </header>     
    <ul>
      {{#each tasks}}    
        {{> task}}    
      {{/each}}    
    </ul>    
  </div>
```

**EDIT**: Maybe a better example here:

```
Template.loaderboard.helpers({
    player: function() {
        return "Hello player";
    },
    videoPlayer: function() {
        return $(".video-player").videoPlayer(); // Pseudo-code
    }
});
```

and in your HTML:

```
<template name="leaderboard">
    {{player}}
    {{videoPlayer}}
</template>
```