# How to add js and css files that are part of an npm dependency to <head> in Meteor 1.4?

Tags: meteor, npm, slider

For example, I want to use Slider Pro in my meteor project as an npm package without having to create an Atmosphere package out of it, however the docs (https://github.com/bqworks/slider-pro) say to include files in `<head>`. [See Image Snippet of Docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDDfX.png). How would I do that?

Comment: You can probably `npm install` it and import the css and js files from any file that uses them in your project. This plugin is distributed with jQuery and does not specify it as a dependency, so you would have to either install and import jQuery from its own npm package or from the slider package. Alternatively, you could create a local Meteor package for it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38765546/including-javascript-in-a-meteor-template/38765786#38765786

Comment: Too late lol already made it into a Meteor/Atmosphere package, much easier on my project's folder structure, and the package size is less than if I have it as an npm package. `fvpdev:slider-pro`

But @ghybs it seems like the solution you referenced is good, thnx

Comment: @fvpDev thank you for the feedback! Well, with the Atmosphere package, at least other people will be able to use it as-is now, so you should be proud to having contributed to the Meteor community! :-) Please make sure your page is well documented, so that people can find and use it easily.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you could do this.  Either way you choose you still need to add it as an npm package through Meteor:

`meteor npm install --save slider-pro`

And then what I commonly do, is create a file inside `imports/startup/client` directory called `vendor.js`, and just use this code in the `vendor.js` file:

```
import '../../../node_modules/slider-pro/dist/js/jquery.sliderPro.js';
import '../../../node_modules/slider-pro/dist/css/slider-pro.css';
```

Then in the file located at `imports/startup/index.js` just add this to include that `vendor.js` file:

`import './vendor.js';`

You just need to make sure that the path is correct, in the `vendor.js` file, as you can see, since my `vendor.js` file is nested 3 directories deeper than the `node_modules` directory, all files have to be prepended with `../../../` which basically means "go back three directories"